# TypeError : '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' on form

Tags: python, forms, validation, typeerror, cs50

I'm learning python from cs50 web programming Edx and working on form adding tasks. The code is adding tasks if form is valid , if not then back to the page at (server side validation).

I'm using Python3.

My code:

```
# created two form inputs 
class NewTaskForm(forms.Form):
    task = forms.CharField(label="Task/kaam")
    priority = forms.IntegerField(label="Priority", min_value=1, max_value="8")

# to show the added tasks
def index(request):
    return render(request, "tasks/index.html", {'tasks': tasks})


# to add the task 
def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewTaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.cleaned_data["task"]
            tasks.append(task)
        else:
            return render(request, "tasks/add.html", {"form": form})

    return render(request, "tasks/add.html",
                  {"form": NewTaskForm()}
                  )
```

Comment: There is no `>` in your code, can you please include a stack trace?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Shouldn't the ```max_value``` be an integer?  i.e. ```max_value=8```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you used a string here:

```
# created two form inputs 
class NewTaskForm(forms.Form):
    task = forms.CharField(label="Task/kaam")
    priority = forms.IntegerField(label="Priority", min_value=1, max_value="8") #<--- max_value="8"
```

try:

```
# created two form inputs 
class NewTaskForm(forms.Form):
    task = forms.CharField(label="Task/kaam")
    priority = forms.IntegerField(label="Priority", min_value=1, max_value=8)

# to show the added tasks
def index(request):
    return render(request, "tasks/index.html", {'tasks': tasks})


# to add the task 
def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewTaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.cleaned_data["task"]
            tasks.append(task)
        else:
            return render(request, "tasks/add.html", {"form": form})

    return render(request, "tasks/add.html",
                  {"form": NewTaskForm()}
                  )
```